# C++ Destruct Function Error!

Tags: c++

I wrote a program that cannot work properly.The problem is that when I destruct the pointer it goes all wrong.

the code is as follows:

```
if(pImage)
    delete pImage;
```

but if i use this code, it can work all right.

```
    if(!pImage)
    delete pImage;
```

can you explain the reasons ? thank you !

Comment: Easily! Your second version works because it skips over the `delete` and just leaks the object. Your first version crashes due to your error in the code which you didn't show us.

Comment: To clarify what @atzz said, in the second case it skips the `delete` because `delete NULL` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example will for sure not work correct - at least not the form of correct you want it to be.
If `pImage` is any non-zero value, the `delete` statement won't be executed. It may compile and work fine, but you're leaking memory (and possibly other resources). Your problem is most likely double-deletion, aka deleting a pointer twice.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't change `pImage`. That's why. `pImage` still points somewhere, but now the memory it is pointing to was already destructed.

Answer (score 0):

your first version
if(pImage)
 delete pImage;

checks if the pointer is there. As you have declared it , it will work fine. You should set it to NULL when you declare it i.e pImage = NULL; so that if the pointer is not pointing to anything, the line will skip. In case something is allocated , the above line will(if statement then becomes true) dealloc the memory given to it. Remember that pImage needs to bee a DYNAMICALLY allocated memory and that after delete, it SHOULD NEVER BE ACCESSED or it will generate the error again.

your second version 
if(!pImage)
delete pImage

is logically wrong. It means IF the pImage does not exist, delete it so this IF statement becomes false. By good practice, if you HAD made that pointer NULL, it would of given you an error here since it logically wrong. 
YOUR saying IF pImage DOES NOT EXIST, DELETE IT !!!!!!!
So the line will probably skip when it has been allocated memory.

(REAL ISSUE IS THAT YOU SHOULD ALWAYS SET A POINTER TO **NULL** when declaring it. You do that, and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocated memory for pImage using **new** then delete may work; but if you have allocated memory using malloc() or if the pointer points to another memory not allocated using new then you are in trouble when calling delete.

Please reply as to how you allocated the memory for pImage in the first place.

Comment: I use new to construct a class pointer ,and when the program ends , I destruct it. ps: I write a MFC program and I am a learner.

Comment: @DeerCoder: Can you paste your code on how you create this pImage and the class definition code so it will be easy for us to help you? How do you arrive at the conclusion that there is something wrong, did you get any run-time errors or messages? You only mentioned in your question that the code goes all wrong, but what exactly happens and how do you conclude it is all wrong?

Comment: Sorry,the code is too long, and it break down when I use the other form, so I think it goes all wrong. But after my debugging, I find that if I don't delete pImage then it can work as well, so I wonder whether there is memory leak?